# WatsonException: Error: invalid request: 'text' is in invalid format, Code: 400

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'm getting the following error when I try running Natural language understanding from IBM blumex

```
WatsonException: Error: invalid request: 'text' is in invalid format, Code: 400
```

this is my code

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1, NaturalLanguageClassifierV1
import watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding.features.v1 as Features
natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
    username='**********',
    password='********',
    version ="2017-02-27")

response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
    text= [i for i in str(sentences)],
    features=[Features.Sentiment()])

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

and this is how sentences look like

```
["' فينو الاهبل ابن الاهبل '",
 "' على المصرييييين وجمالهم ربنا يحميهم لينك 6 '",
 "' منشن دول كتير اوى ودمهم خفيف العمارة اللي انا فيها كلها سوريين والءطفال عسل '",
 "' انا بعد كده خلى اللى يوعنى بحاجه همضى على وصل امانه علشان اضمن انو مش يخون '",
 "' انا هنتحر '",
 "' في حفظ الله يا ريس لينك 9 '",
 "' يا عيون عطشان عطشانة سهر يا قلوب تعبانة تعبانة سفر كتروا من الحب تلاقوا تلاقوا في الضلمة ءلف قمر '",
 "' زهقنا من اسامي اكونتات البنات على مواقع التواصل الاجتماعي زي مثلا شروق الشمس و الذهب الءزرق و ءي بطيخ و السلام '",
 "' منشن 793 حمد الله ع السلامة '",
 "' منشن07 ءحا مين '",
 "' لما تشوف حد واحشك كان بقالك كتير مشفتوش '"]
```

how can I run the sentiment analysis service on the through the python sdk on IBM Blumex
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe `natural_language_understanding.analyze()` expects `text` to be a string. From the docs (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/?python#post-analyze):

> The "text" attribute accepts plain text.

You are giving it a list. Additionally, your list has extra quotes in it which makes it hard to simply join as a singe string.

You might try evaluating the individual elements of the array with `ast.literal_eval()` and then join the results into one string.

```
import ast

text = ' '.join([ast.literal_eval(i) for i in sen])
```

This should change your array of sentences into one string:

> ' فينو الاهبل ابن الاهبل   على المصرييييين وجمالهم ربنا يحميهم لينك 6   منشن دول كتير اوى ودمهم خفيف العمارة اللي انا فيها كلها سوريين والءطفال عسل   انا بعد كده خلى اللى يوعنى بحاجه همضى على وصل امانه علشان اضمن انو مش يخون   انا هنتحر   في حفظ الله يا ريس لينك 9   يا عيون عطشان عطشانة سهر يا قلوب تعبانة تعبانة سفر كتروا من الحب تلاقوا تلاقوا في الضلمة ءلف قمر   زهقنا من اسامي اكونتات البنات على مواقع التواصل الاجتماعي زي مثلا شروق الشمس و الذهب الءزرق و ءي بطيخ و السلام   منشن 793 حمد الله ع السلامة   منشن07 ءحا مين   لما تشوف حد واحشك كان بقالك كتير مشفتوش '

If you want to analyze each element separately then you'll need to call `natural_language_understanding.analyze()` on each element with something like:

```
for tweet in sentences:
    response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
        text= tweet,
        features=[Features.Sentiment()]
    )
    print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

Comment: but each one is a separate tweet I want to get the sentiment for each tweet separately. How can I do so?

Comment: Oh, then you need to call `natural_language_understanding.analyze()` for each element of the array.

Comment: I realized that and tried this again 

blumex = []
for x in sentences:
    response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
        text= x,
        features=[Features.Sentiment()])
    blumex.append(response)

but I get the following error again 

WatsonException: Error: unsupported text language: fa, Code: 400

Comment: It is supported. I checked the code runs I get some results and I get this error in the end I think there is a problem in one of the tweets

Comment: Any Idea how to overcome this ?

Comment: It looks like it is interpreting your text as Farsi -- 'unsupported text language: fa'  The function takes a language parameter, you might try setting the  language and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you analyze text or a web page, Natural Language Understanding detects the source language automatically and returns the corresponding `ISO 639-1` code in the response. For automatic language detection to work best, *it is recommended that you use text with at least 100 characters*.

Like @Mark_M said, you need to set the language and see if that helps.

One example, in your `sentence` sent to analyze, you need to use the following example:

```
{
  "text": "...X, Y, Z, now I know my A, B, Cs",
  "features": {
    "semantic_roles": {}
  },
  "language": "en"
}
```

Obs.: One good idea is to translate to English to use more features for this API.

Obs II.: Please note this answer is just one complement.

- You can see the Watson NLU Documentation the [Supported languages.](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/index.html)
- See your parameter to set inside the JSON object [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/detectable-languages.html).
- See one [example](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/overriding-language-detection.html) setting the language using cURL to have some base example.